# SQL group rows into pairs

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to add some sort of unique identifier (uid) to partitions made of pairs of rows, i.e. generate some uid/tag for each two rows of (identifier1,identifier2) in a window partition with size = 2 rows.

So, for example, the first 2 rows for ID X would get uid A, the next two rows for the same ID would get uid B and, if there is only one single row left in the partition for ID X, it would get id C.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, the picture illustrates the table's structure, I manually added the expectedIdentifier to illustrate the goal:

[image]

This is my current SQL, ntile doesn't solve it because the partition size varies:

```
select
rowId
, ntile(2) over (partition by firstIdentifier, secondIdentifier order by timestamp asc) as ntile
, *
from log;
```

Already tried ntile( (count(*) over partition...) / 2), but that doesn't work.

Generating the UID can be done with md5() or similar, but I'm having trouble tagging the rows as illustrated above (so I can md5 the generated tag/uid)

Answer (score 1):

While count(*) is not supported within a Snowflake window function, count(1) is supported and can be used to create the unique identifier.  Below is an example of an integer unique ID matching pairs of rows and handling "odd" row groups:

```
select 
ntile(2) over (partition by firstIdentifier, secondIdentifier order by timestamp asc) as ntile
,ceil(count(1) over( partition by firstIdentifier, secondIdentifier order by timestamp asc) / 2) as id
, *
from log;
```

Comment: Almost solved it, but the highlighted row should be set to 1 instead of 2: https://imgur.com/a/MGv7yrC

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem: even when timestamps are identical as in your screenshot, I continue to get pairs of 1,2,3 for that data.  Can you post the full SQL that you are using to generate the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, char(65 + (row_number() over(partition by 
firstidentifier,secondidentifier order by timestamp)-1)/2) 
expectedidentifier from log 
order by firstidentifier, timestamp
```

Here is the Sql Server Version

```
with log (firstidentifier,secondidentifier, timestamp)
as (
select 15396, 14460, 1 union all
select 15396, 14460, 1 union all
select 19744, 14451, 1 union all
select 19744, 14451, 1 union all
select 19744, 14451, 1 union all
select 15590, 12404, 1 union all
select 15590, 12404, 1 union all
select 15590, 12404, 1 union all
select 15590, 12404, 1 union all
select 15590, 12404, 1 
)
select *, char(65 + (row_number() over(partition by 
firstidentifier,secondidentifier order by timestamp)-1)/2) 
expectedidentifier from log 
order by firstidentifier,secondidentifier,timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't output the expected result

Comment: Sorry, I missed the case the timestamps are identical. Updated the query with row_number.. this should work now.